# How to animate views as the ViewPager position offset changes

Tags: android, animation

We would like to create an app intro with animation where the user scrolls through pages and, as the user scrolls, a view is animated and travels through all the slides. The animated view should move as the user scrolls, so if the user scrolls faster the animated view should move faster and if the user scrolls back to a previous page, the animated view should move backwards.

This is super easy in iOS with https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands but I can't find a way to do this in Android.

Problems I've found:

- Animations run in real time; you can't let the time be the ViewPager offset.
- In `FragmentPagerAdapter`, views from one fragment can't be moved to another fragment.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Do I understand correctly if you want to have a view 'lazily' follow the scrolling, so to speak?

Comment: Yes, sort of that. In my answer below I use `onPageScrolled` to use the `position + positionOffset` as the "interpolation point".

Comment: Not that I come up with an answer but I would think that you would have to put the ViewPager inside a FrameLayout, then position the view you want to animate on top of your ViewPager. From then on you could continue the onPageScrolled approach, moving the view accordingly.

Comment: need to move to vie different position while change the page  .Any library available for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second problem:

The viewPagerAdapter will destroy the views when they are no more needed so to keep a view visible through all the pages you need add it to the layout that contains the ViewPager.

Something like this can works:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_transparent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text out of view pager"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 @pedro,works great but what if i want to translate my textview to second page but not the third,how can i stop my view from translating it to the other pages.

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer. It's for the first problem.

- Animations run in real time; you can't let the time be the ViewPager offset.

I can change the properties of the animated view in the `onPageScrolled` method of `OnPageChangeListener` of the `ViewPager`.

This is a simple example that changes the left margin of the animated view so it moves to the right.

```
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);

            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) animatedView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins((int) ((position + positionOffset) * 500), 0, 0, 0);
            animatedView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

The second problem is not solved, though. When the view reaches the right side of the page it is in, it disappears. In other words, the view can't move to the next page (fragment).

Comment: what if we want to move the vie up and down?

Comment: better use `animatedView.setTranslationX(positionOffsetPixels * -1f);`, it's one line code