# Welcome screen with moving object on sliding the screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to do this ([Please see the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5oJ34gPmZqdzJOMGsyMmk2TG8/view)). I have already Googled it but did not find any solution. Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: please read this https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.yrch7b8zv

Comment: and look through ViewPager.PageTransformer()

Comment: and one ore http://stackoverflow.com/a/22501679/2685996

Comment: check https://medium.com/android-news/creating-an-intro-screen-for-your-app-using-viewpager-pagetransformer-9950517ea04f#.97ufezjzz

Answer (score 1):

probabily you are looking for this -

https://github.com/sacot41/SCViewPager
and 
https://github.com/Nightonke/WoWoViewPager

-Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my following steps:

1. Just Add your video in asset folder with `.mp4` extension.
2. Use this method on Splash screen to Play video.
   `vidHolder is videoview`.

   ```
       private void PlayVideo() {
       Uri video = null;

       DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
       getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
       try {
           Intent intent = getIntent();
           if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
               isLogout = intent.getStringExtra("isLogout");
           }
          /* if (isLogout != null && isLogout.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
               playAnimation();
               //*video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.logutvideo);*//
           } else {*/
           video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash_revised);
           //  }
           vidHolder.setVideoURI(video);
           vidHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           vidHolder.setZOrderOnTop(false);
           vidHolder.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
               @Override
               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   Log.e("First","11");
                   vidHolder.seekTo(0);
                   vidHolder.start();
                   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       }
                   }, 300);
               }
           });

           vidHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   jump();
               }
           });
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           jump();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i want to move object on sliding the screen left to right and right to left

Comment: Apply animation to individual objects. May be this will help .http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html